# Python 2.7.3 IndentationError: expected an indented block - cant find mistake

Tags: python, indentation

I am new to python and trying to submit my HW on Coursera Data Science course. The environment there is VM running Python 2.7.3, the file tweet_sentiment.py I am trying to run has the following script within it:

```
import sys
import json

def hw():
    print 'Hello, world!'

def lines(fp):
    print str(len(fp.readlines()))

def main():
    sent_file = open(sys.argv[1])
    tweet_file = open(sys.argv[2])
    # hw()
    # lines(sent_file)
    # lines(tweet_file)

    myfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    mydict = {}
    for line in lines:
    key, value = line.split("\t")
        mydict[key] = int(value)

    twit_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
    twit_lines = twit_file.readlines()

    mylist = []
    for line in twit_lines:
    mylist.append(json.loads(line))

    for listik in mylist:
    twit_value = 0
    twit_text = listik["text"]
    twit_words = twit_text.split()
    for word in twit_words:
        if word in mydict:
        twit_value =  twit_value + 1
    print float(twit_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running $ python tweet_sentiment.py I am getting the following error:

```
    File "tweet_sentiment.py", line 25
    key, value = line.split("\t")
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Thanks for any hints!
Sergey

Comment: Think about it this way: A `for` statement only loops over the lines that are indented. Since you don't have any indented lines, it has nothing to do. Since that's almost certainly not what you want, Python is being nice and giving you an error, instead of treating it as a loop that wastes a bunch of time doing absolutely nothing.

Comment: Also, you have the same problem with at least one two places: `for line in twit_lines:` and `if word in mydict:`.

Comment: Finally, it's worth noting that all one of the loops you got wrong (that I noticed, at least) could be replaced with a one-line list comprehension, dict comprehension, or `collections.Counter`, which means you didn't even need to indent anything here anyway…

Comment: @abarnert, try editing the question and move the cursor left and right over those whitespaces, you'll see the tabs there.

Comment: @gnibbler: Actually, it looks like he's got tabs and spaces in the same line, to make things even more confusing. That's why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful! You're mixing tabs and spaces for indenting.

Often a tab is displayed as the equivalent of 8 spaces. So, when using the common practice of 4 spaces it *looks* like 2 levels of indentation, but is really only one.

When I examine your code in the editor, I can see that you've got  in at least two places. Replace those tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: +1 Just to add to what @gnibbler says, [_PEP8_](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) warns about just this, and recommends the use of spaces over tabs. (4 spaces per indentation level)

Answer (score 2):

As it says, you have an indentation error. Line 25 should be corrected to this:

```
def main():

...

    for line in lines:
        key, value = line.split("\t")
        mydict[key] = int(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent the line after a `for` block. Your code should look like:

```
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.split("\t")
    mydict[key] = int(value)
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Sorry for posting this mess,I looked like I am asking really basic question. 
Indentation was actually well organized in my file, but when copying it to post, formatting got lost and I did not check that.

Eventually my file was successfully executed by the course script which checks assignment and results went out right. I am not sure why it did not work when running on VM. 

Thanks for prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be like this:

```
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.split("\t")
    mydict[key] = int(value)
```

It's the same for all other for's.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import sys
import json

def hw():
    print 'Hello, world!'

def lines(fp):
    print str(len(fp.readlines()))

def main():
    sent_file = open(sys.argv[1])
    tweet_file = open(sys.argv[2])
    # hw()
    # lines(sent_file)
    # lines(tweet_file)

    myfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    mydict = {}
    for line in lines:
        key, value = line.split("\t")
        mydict[key] = int(value)

    twit_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
    twit_lines = twit_file.readlines()

    mylist = []
    for line in twit_lines:
        mylist.append(json.loads(line))

    for listik in mylist:
        twit_value = 0
        twit_text = listik["text"]
        twit_words = twit_text.split()
        for word in twit_words:
            if word in mydict:
            twit_value =  twit_value + 1
            print float(twit_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The indentation for the `for` statements is messed up. The `for` block has to be indented. Also, as stated before, Python will throw an error if you mix tabs and spaces. Use either all spaces(replace each tab with 4 spaces) or all tabs(replace every 4 spaces with a tab).

Comment: Thanks! 

Sorry for posting this mess,I looked like I am asking really basic question. 
Indentation was actually well organized in my file, but when copying it to post, formatting got lost and I did not check that.

Eventually my file was successfully executed by the course script which checks assignment and results went out right. I am not sure why it did not work when running on VM. 

Thanks for prompt response!

Comment: @SergeySamusev: You're welcome! The error was an indentation error. Might have had something to do with...well...I don't really know. All I can say is...good luck! Maybe the indentation was like one space off or didn't correlate with the rest of the file. I make that seemingly novice mistake all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vim` to open it. And then type the commoand `：retab`
It then shows the line not correctly indented.